# Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant?

Tags: c++, comma-operator

I'm getting errors on lines `102, 115, and 128`. What am I doing wrong? It says:

> Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

and I don't know what that means. I've tried to fix this for a week now, and it's due in my C++ class this coming Wednesday. I could really use some outside advice here. What am I doing wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double qMeter = 0;
double hMeter = 0;
double oneMeter = 0;
int solDay = 0;
string garbage;
string localTime;
string decSol;
ifstream input;
ofstream output;

//function prototypes
double low(double lowTemp);
double high(double highTemp);
float average(double avgTemp);

int main()
{

input.open("curiosity234x.dat"); //opens input data file
output.open("output.dat"); //opens output data file


  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //gets rid of the first four lines
{
  getline(input,garbage);
  cout << endl;
}

while (!input.eof())
{
    int count; 
    double newOneMeter;
    double newHMeter;
    double newQMeter;

    if (solDay == 2) //processes data for the second solar day
    {
     input >> solDay >> localTime >> decSol 
     >> newOneMeter >> newHMeter >> newQMeter;

     oneMeter = oneMeter + newOneMeter;
     hMeter = hMeter + newHMeter;
     qMeter = qMeter + newQMeter;
     count++;

     output << solDay << fixed << setprecision(1) << setw(5)
        << "Solar" << "Average" << "Low" << "High"
        << "Average" << "Low" << "High" 
        << "Average" << "Low" << "High" 
        << "Day" << "Temp" << "Temp" << "Temp" << "Temp" << "Temp"
        << "Temp" << "Temp" << "Temp" << "Temp"
        << fixed << setprecision(15) << "1 meter" << ".5 meters"
        << ".25 meters"
        << average(oneMeter) << low(oneMeter) << high(oneMeter)
        << average(hMeter) << low(hMeter) << high(hMeter)
        << average(qMeter) << low(qMeter) << high(qMeter);
    }

    if (solDay == 3) //processes data for the third solar day
    {
     input >> solDay >> localTime >> decSol 
     >> newOneMeter >> newHMeter >> newQMeter;

     oneMeter = oneMeter + newOneMeter;
     hMeter = hMeter + newHMeter;
     qMeter = qMeter + newQMeter;
     count++;

     output << solDay << fixed << setprecision(1) << setw(5)
        << "Solar" << "Average" << "Low" << "High" 
        << average(oneMeter) << low(oneMeter) << high(oneMeter)
        << average(hMeter) << low(hMeter) << high(hMeter)
        << average(qMeter) << low(qMeter) << high(qMeter);
    }
  }

  cout << endl << "The output.dat file has been written and transmitted.";
  /*
  reads first line. Assigns first string to 'int solDay' 
  second to 'string time', third to decSol, fourth to oneMeter, 
  fifth to hMeter and sixth to qmeter. Meters should have setw().
  */
getch();
return 0;

input.close();
output.close();
}


//functions used in main
double low(double lowTemp)
{
   int test = 10,000;
   double least;

   if (lowTemp < test)
   {
     lowTemp = test;
     lowTemp = least;       
    }
    return least;
}

double high(double highTemp)
{
   int test = 10,000;
   double most;

   if (highTemp < test)
   {
      highTemp = test;
      highTemp = most;        
    }
   return most;
}

float average(double avgTemp)
{
   avgTemp = avgTemp / count;
   return avgTemp;
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `while (!eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors on line 102 and 115 are due to the fact that you have a *comma* in `10,000`, but it should be `10000`, the *comma* can not be used as a numeric separator. What you are actually using is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which evaluates it's expressions from *left to right* and only returns the last one. So in this case:

```
int test = 10,000;
           ^  ^
           |  Expression 2
           Expression 1
```

since `=` has higher precedence it happens first and your are left with a syntax error, on the other hand:

```
int test = (10,000);
```

would have resulted in the value `10` being discarded and *octal literal* `000` being assigned to `test`.

The final error on line 128 is due to the fact that count is local to `main` but you are trying to use it in `average`, you need to pass `count` as a second paramter.

Comment: The funny thing is that it actually compiles if you change it to `int test = (10,000);`. Of course that leaves `test` being 0, though.

Comment: Should have added link to explanation of the comma operator, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 8):

I searched this error when I ran into it.  The cause of my troubles?  I was trying to give a class the same name as #define value that had been included into my project from a 3rd party API header.  Trying a different class name, I got it to compile!

Comment: For whom is arrived here googling, like me, consider Joel answer. It also happened to me. I wanted to define const bool HIGH/LOW in a code that was including wiringPi.h libs for rasperryPi: unfortunatly wiringPi define (#define) HIGH/LOW... Thanks to Joel that make me have this suspect!

Comment: @maxbeltra but unfortunately it does not answer this question.

Comment: I've got the same problem and google for text "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant", well, this answer solves my problem.